# Facebook Graph API alternative to user.hasAppPermission in facebook old rest api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook C# SDK( https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk ), and am wondering if there is a graph api function that can get user's granted permission to my application, like

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/users.hasAppPermission?ext_perm=offline_access&access_token=XXXXXXXXX&format=json
```

So I want some thing like this

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/hasAppPermission
```

so that I can call the Facebook C# SDK API to Post with this url and a dictionary object with parameters.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook added Graph call for this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions
```

which returns JSON structure like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "read_stream":1,
            "status_update":1,
            "photo_upload":1,
            "publish_stream":1,
            "user_photos":1
        }
    ]
}
```

Documentation:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 2):

There is no graph call to do what you want. You will have to use the REST API call. I suggest you don't use that Facebook API as it does not have a lot of features. Try the [FacebookSDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com) as it is a lot more advanced and being regularly updated